# What is a "model" in machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, terminology, model

In every machine learning discussion, the term "model" is used to describe how the prediction is made. Does this "model" refer to the learning algorithm used? What exactly is a model?

Answer (score 2):

Think of machine learning as learning formula for a task (say making a prediction). Model is then the unique formula. Learning algorithm is the procedure by which you arrive at the right formula.

If you are building a machine learning model of the form (linear regression),

Y = a<sub>0</sub> * x<sub>0</sub> + a<sub>1</sub> * x<sub>1</sub> + ... + a<sub>n</sub> * x<sub>n</sub>

Then the linear formula above has free parameters a<sub>0</sub> .. a<sub>n</sub>. For a fixed value of all parameters, you have a unique formula. This unique formula/equation is the *model*. Model is something that you can save and use to make predictions on new inputs.

Comment: Can we say the Theta (or Hypothesis) which is used to get predicted y (for a given x) is the Model ?  When algorithms like Decision Trees or Random Forest is used, they derive upon a Model based on their training set and this model is used to make the prediction for the unseen data. Is this understanding correct ?

Comment: $\theta$ is not a model but the parameters of a (parametric) model.

Answer (score 2):

The term "model" is generally used in one of two slightly different ways.

It can refer to a [statistical model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_model). Formally, this is a set of probability distributions. A "learning algorithm" tries to find a distribution from this set which matches the data best. There are different types of statistical models. [Linear models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_model) and most neural networks correspond to [parametric models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_model). Here, each element of the set is identified by a vector of parameters.

$$\mathcal{P} = \{ p_\theta : \theta \in \Theta \}$$

A linear regression model could be written as

$$\mathcal{P} = \{ \mathcal{N}(y; \mathbf{a}^\top \mathbf{x} + b, 1) : \mathbf{a} \in \mathbb{R}^n, b \in \mathbb{R}\}.$$

In neural networks, the network's architecture defines the set of possible distributions, and the weights and biases identify distributions from that set.

Other types of statistical models are [graphical models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_model), in which the family of distributions is determined by a graph, or [non-parametric models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonparametric_statistics), in which the number of parameters is not fixed.

The other use of "model" in machine learning is to refer to a particular instance of a statistical model. I.e., instead of $\mathcal{P}$, "model" can refer to a particular $p_\theta$ where $\theta$ might be the parameter vector found by a learning algorithm.

It is also common to use terms to describe a combination of models and algorithms. For example, the term "linear regression" is generally understood to mean maximum likelihood estimation in the linear model. Another example would be [variational autoencoders](https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.6114), which refers to variational inference in certain neural network based generative models.